# jQuery AJAX Pagination not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have the ajax library added at the header of the `HTML` and also `twitter-bootstrap library` im trying to load the data without any trigger from the php but the php works fine i try to open the data.php it makes an output there are no errors in the console but i really dont know why it's not working what seems to be the problem?

**HTML** is

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>age</th>
         <th>address</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id = "user_data">
</table>
```

**jQuery** is

```
$(document).ready(function(){


     function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#user_data').html(data);  
                 alert('Successfully called');
            },
            error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
           })  
      } 

      load_data(1);

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      }); 
});
```

no need to add the php its working fine it output what i need this is just the problem thanks!

**UPDATED**

i tried using those alert this doesnt alert anything?
[The Response from Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGunv.png)

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdImG.png)

the line refferring in the error in cosole is `$('#user_data').html(data);`

Comment: and also on the NETWORK there is no data.php

Comment: Your load_data function expects a page number as parameter.. when you are calling it for the first time you are not passing the page parameter..

Comment: how will i going to pass a page parameter? is it from the php?

Comment: When you refresh the page if its always page 1 then you can pass it directly..if you are embedding the page in URL, you can $_GET it from URL an assign to the variable..

Comment: So basically after document ready, try this load_data(1)

Comment: still doesn't work even the `alert('successfully called')`

Comment: Okay can you delete load_data() from the top and add load_data(1) after function load_data(page) ends?

Comment: Is there any error in console? Or check in network tab if request if going through and response is coming as expected..

Comment: there is no error in console.. the network tab is empty request isn't working

Comment: ive seen a response how can i attach image here?

Comment: You can update your answer and add image in that for reference..

Comment: i think the `success:function(data)` doesnt work

Comment: i found errors, wait i will upload the image

Comment: Can you close the <tbody> tag in html. Also check if response tags are properly closed. Also tbody expects <tr> as immediate child which needs to be closed as well. Also can you console.log(data) and remove everything in success function to check ?

Comment: thank you for helping how can i commend you?

Comment: Did your issue got resolved? I will post it as answer in here :)

Comment: yes `alert('sucessfully called')` works but data still no output wait for a bit haha :)

Comment: Lol :P check about the html tags from response because everything else looks proper.

Comment: haha its working now can i please ask 1 more question? can you help me to use buttons from the datas i get? its working now thanks for your help it displays the datas but the buttons are not working?

Comment: post solution for checking my a HTML tags in the fetch php haha i will commend you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to make sure the HTML tags are properly closed and also hierarchy or tags is maintained while appending/adding HTML by ajax. For example  tag expects  as immediate child.

Also, when you are adding click events to any elements like buttons which are added dynamically post dom load, make sure you use on click instead of direct click.

In your click event function for ".pagination_link", make sure you are getting the id in page variable. I prefer using a attribute like 'page' so that you can get attr('page') as its more readable.

Comment: i fetched a button from that ajax functions with an html of `<input type = "submit" id = "add_details">` it works with these method  `$(document).on('click', '#add_details', function(){  
           alert('buttons works')
      }); ` but how can i submit a form that this button is its parent?

Comment: you can see that input type from the **The Response from Network Tab**

Comment: there's also a form :)

Comment: So basically the button is outside the form tag right? You can do in button click : var parent = $(this).closest('tr'); $('form', parent).submit(); the second argument parent will make sure that it submits try form enclosed in the same tr the button in placed in

Comment: how can i commend you for the second time? answer this question your logic works fine :D haha [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829750/how-to-submit-a-form-from-ajax-callback?noredirect=1#comment74696857_43829750)