# How to submit a FORM from ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

through my journey on understanding ajax i came up with this problem and i don't know how to solve it first im requesting for datas in my table

```
load_data();
function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"data.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                },
                error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}                
           })  
      }
```

this is just the table where it will be output

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>details</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id = "result">
```

and this is the output from network tab

[Response from network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEq56.png)

there's a button from the response i tried to activate it using this jquery to submit its form but this doesn't work

```
  $(document).on('click', '#add_details', function(){  
       $(this).parents("form").submit();
  });
```

Comment: where is `add_details`

Comment: Where's the rest of the logic? When/where is executed `load_data()`?

Comment: Why not **parent** instead of **parents**?

Answer (score 0):

add id to the form you need to submit with button click like

```
<form id="myForm1">
//Other Code Here
```

and with your button just Use the id you added

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_details', function(){  
       $("#myForm1").submit();
});
```